# How can I configure the omnisharp syntastic syntax checker to be more lenient?

Tags: c#, vim, syntastic, omnisharp

I've followed [this guide](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim) for setting up my vim for c#. I works beautifully, but I've got an annoyance: The syntastic checker is a bit too harsh on me. Specifically it advises me to change this line:

```
var parser = new Parser(configuration, findReservations: true);
```

with the message "Redundant argument name specification". Of course I COULD just do as it says, but I happen to like my redundant argument specification. The reader of my code might not remember what that boolean is for otherwise. So... how can I tell syntastic (or omnisharp) to relax about this kind of warning?

Comment: I've read http://www.omnisharp.net/ or https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim. If there are any more detailed documentation I haven't found, please enlighten me.

Comment: If you didn't find anything relevant there like command-line flags, inline flags to put in your code or options to put in a global or per-project config file then there's almost certainly no way to do what you want. But I doubt it, as even javascript linters have that kind of flag or configuration facilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the `config.json` file in the `/bin/Debug` folder of the server. On my machine the server is located in `~/.vim/bundle/Omnisharp/server/OmniSharp`.

You'll see some example ignored code issues in the [default config file](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/blob/f87a0641cf3cc1d277b4403cbd9dc4f5cb0e2821/OmniSharp/config.json#L29).

To ignore this particular issue, add this rule:

```
"^Redundant argument name specification$"
```

If this is the only rule, besides the default rules, the IgnoredCodeIssues section of the `config.js` file will look like this:

```
"IgnoredCodeIssues": [
  "^Keyword 'private' is redundant. This is the default modifier.$",
  ".* should not separate words with an underscore.*",
  "^Redundant argument name specification$" 
],
```